# Типы данных в JavaScript. Преобразование типов

Tags: javascript, преобразование-типов

`[] == false` даст **true**;
`{} == false` даст **false**;

Почему

```
if ({} && []) {   
   alert( "Все объекты - true!" ); // alert сработает 
}
```

или даже

```
if ([]) {   
   alert( "true!" ); // alert сработает 
}
```

даст **true**?

Answer (score 0):

Преобразование к **true/false** происходит в логическом контексте, таком как if(value), и при применении логических операторов.

**[]** и **{}** - объекты. А объекты в этом контексте всегда дают **true**.

Больше инфы [здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/types-conversion#%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5).